# Making target commit the current index

Tags: git

How do I make target `<treeish>` the current index?

I'm looking for something kind of like `git checkout <treeish> -- .` for the working directory and index, but for the index only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the "plumbing" command

```
git read-tree <treeish>
```

is for.

If you add the `-m` option, it will keep stat info for files that match so following checkout-index or diff won't think they need to do anything with them. If you pass more than one *treeish*, it merges them (and produces multi-stage index in case of conflicts). See [git read-tree(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) for more details.